# Easy Search for Renamed Units

Tags: warhammer-fantasy, age-of-sigmar

I am just now getting started with Warhammer: Age of Sigmar and I have found something that is confusing and difficult to remedy. In the free Warscroll pdfs for The Empire army, it lists several units named with **'Empire'** (*Empire Greatswords, Empire Pistoliers, etc.*), but in the General's Handbook and Skirmish books, it appears those same units have had their names changed to use **'Freeguild'** instead (*Freeguils Greatswords, Freeguild Pisoliers, etc.*). Now, I wouldn't think it is such a big deal, but I cannot find anything that, for lack of a better why to describe it, a simple changelog of units that have been updated with new names, and in some cases new keywords and rules. Is ther any sort of log that exists? If so, where do I need to look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of '8-25-17', coinciding with Games Workshop's "General's Handbook 2017," Warhammer Community has released updated FAQs for the Grand Alliances, as well as updated the legacy Compendiums for the old armies (*Bretonnia, Beastmen, Tomb Kings, etc*). In these Compendiums, at the very end, there are list of units with Substitute Warscrolls, as was stated by user '**aslum**' on '7-31-17' that now includes not just Named and out-of-production models, but also models that have had their unit's name changed for the Age of Sigmar lore (*Empire Greatsword -> Freeguild Greatsword for example*) and updated Pitched Battle profiles for legacy units. [Here is a direct link to them.](https://www.warhammer-community.com/2017/08/25/new-and-updated-faqs-forge-world-warscrolls-and-compendium-pdfsgw-homepage-post-1/)

Answer (score 0):

On the Games-Workshop site, under [Age of Sigmar Rules](https://www.games-workshop.com/en-US/Warhammer-Age-of-Sigmar-Rules) at the end of The Empire rules there's a list of Substitute Warscrolls. I've included it below in case GW takes down or moves the rules. I basically just C&Ped it; it could be formatted better.

```
Unit   . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .Warscroll
Ar-Ulric .................................. Warrior Priest
Arch Lector ............................... Warrior Priest
Arch Lector on War Altar of Sigmar ......... War Altar of Sigmar
Battle Wizard Lord ........................ Battle Wizard
Battle Wizard Lord on Pegasus .............. Balthasar Gelt
Captain .................................. Empire General 
Felix ..................................... Militia  Leader 
                            (see Empire Free Company Militia warscroll)
General of the Empire on Pegasus ........... Empire General on Warhorse  
                                             (the model can fly)
Huntsmen ................................ Empire Archers
Imperial Halfling Hot Pot .................. Empire Mortar
Karl Franz on foot ......................... Empire General
Karl Franz on Warhorse .................... Empire General on Warhorse 
Karl Franz on Imperial Pegasus ............. Empire General on Warhorse 
                                            (the model can fly) 
Karl Franz on the Imperial Dragon .......... Karl Franz on Deathclaw
Master Engineer on Warhorse ............... Master Engineer on Mechanical Steed
Teutogen Guard ........................... Greatswords 
Warrior Priest on Warhorse ................ Luthor Huss
```

Comment: I have this list. This list is for models that don't have a their own warscroll associated with them. The problem I have is that some models (and there associated warscrolls) have been completely renamed with no list detailing these changes.